# EF Core database-first, get navigational field name programatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

If an entity has a foreign key connection, it gets properties like this out of the box:

```
public partial class Foo 
{
    public decimal SomeBarKey { get;set; }
    public virtual Bar SomeBarKeyNavigation { get;set; }
}
```

Is there any way to fetch the `SomeBarKeyNavigation` name programatically based on an entity type?

Comment: I did not understand correctly, you want to get the foreign field?https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi Your example is code first, I'm talking about db first. I want to get the Navigational property name programatically, based on an entity type

Comment: You can have more than one Entity of the same type!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the names of the navigation properties:

```cs
var db = new AppDbContext();
var navigations = db.Model
    .FindEntityType(typeof(Foo))
    ?.GetNavigations()
    .Select(n => n.Name);
```

More information on EF metadata at [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata?view=efcore-7.0).